# How do I convert a JSON string object value to an integer?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm tring to convert a JSON object value to an integer and calculate.

It shows `representativeRow.DTA_VAL` well but the value of total shows `NaN`.

I don't think this works because the other code works well.

```
  datav=  Number(representativeRow.DTA_VAL);
```

this is my code

```
  var rows = resp.Sttsapitbldata[1].row;
        if (rows) {
            var representativeRow;
            for (i = 1; i < 30; i++) {
                representativeRow = rows[i];

                if(representativeRow.ITM_NM.substring(0,2)=="부산"){
                   // console.log(representativeRow.ITM_NM);
                    var sub =representativeRow.ITM_NM.substring(0,3);
                    var total;
                    var datav;
                    console.log(representativeRow.DTA_VAL);
                    datav=  Number(representativeRow.DTA_VAL);

                    total+=datav;
                    console.log(total);

                }

                itemNm2 = representativeRow.ITM_NM;
                dataV = representativeRow.DTA_VAL;
                //console.log(itemNm2);
                //console.log(dataV);
                options.data.data.push({locname: itemNm2, listshrs: dataV});
            }


            korea = webponent.visual.korea.init($(".korea"), style, options);

        }
```

See JSON file code below.

```
{"Sttsapitbldata":[{"head":[{"list_total_count":88},{"RESULT":{"CODE":"INFO-000","MESSAGE":"정상 처리되었습니다."}}]},{"row":[{"STATBL_ID":"T183673021266818","DTACYCLE_CD":"YY","WRTTIME_IDTFR_ID":"2016","ITM_ID":10001,"ITM_NM":"계","CLS_ID":50033,"CLS_NM":"강간","UI_NM":"명","DTA_VAL":5155,"DTA_SVAL":null},{"STATBL_ID":"T183673021266818","DTACYCLE_CD":"YY","WRTTIME_IDTFR_ID":"2016","ITM_ID":10002,"ITM_NM":"서울","CLS_ID":50033,"CLS_NM":"강간","UI_NM":"명","DTA_VAL":1129,"DTA_SVAL":null},{"STATBL_ID":"T183673021266818","DTACYCLE_CD":"YY","WRTTIME_IDTFR_ID":"2016","ITM_ID":10003,"ITM_NM":"부산","CLS_ID":50033,"CLS_NM":"강간","UI_NM":"명","DTA_VAL":314,"DTA_SVAL":null},
```

Comment: DTA_VAL seems to be 'null' in your array and null isn't a number. So maybe test for null and convert it to 0  (or whatever you need) first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialise total=0. You can't add to a null value on the first iteration. Although looking at it, I suspect you'd be wanting to initialise total outside of the loop